# How to fit the text content in the UI button using css

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following UI

[image]

And the CSS for the button is below

```
    background-color: #24a5cf !important;
    color: black !important;
    font-size: large !important;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    border-color: #24a5cf !important;
    width: 65% !important;
    border-style: none !important;
    height: 46px !important;
```

I tried as below

```
display: inline-block;
```

but it is not getting fixed. I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Show a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, not just snippets of CSS that lack context.

Comment: You have a fixed size for the button. Either reduce the size of the font or remove the `height: 46px !important`. You can also remove the width property to make it all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the width and height values and provide the dimensions with padding. also you shouldn't use important unless you have to!

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below css styles and the issue got fixed.

padding: 0px;